# Difference between order line item and order meta in WC_Checkout hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a plugin where I am using `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook to add order item meta.

I have a plugin called **WooCommerce TM Extra Product Options** installed. 
This plugin uses `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` hook to add order item meta.

When the plugin is activated, I am getting the plugin's meta fields displayed on the order received page but my meta information is not getting displayed. My meta is getting displayed if the plugin is deactivated or when I comment the `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook.

Comment: You could give the code of your custom plugin hooked in woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta in your question… It should help to understand better your issue.

Answer (score 10):

They are not really for the same things:

- The hook `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` allow for example to add / update the Order meta data so the database table `wp_postmeta`.
- The hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` allow for example to add / update line items type in the Order so in database tables `wp_woocommerce_order_items` (for `line_item` item type (product name)) and in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` *(for `line_item` item type **details** as quantity, line item totals and attributes for product variation,
  attributes…)*.

For the priority (there is not really a priority as they are not made for similar things):

- The action hook [**`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#371) is located in [`WC_Chechout` `create_order_line_items()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#342-376).
- The action hook [`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#329) is located in [`WC_Chechout` `create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#262-335) method at the end.
- As [`create_order_line_items()` is executed **BEFORE**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#314) in [`create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#262-335).
  So `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` **is called before**.

> To add order **item meta**, you should better use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook instead with priority before the **WooCommerce TM Extra Product Options** plugin.

**Example**:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );  
function custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item ) {  
   $item->add_meta_data( 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );  
}
```

[Related: WooCommerce: add different order item meta for each item in order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329664/woocommerce-add-different-order-item-meta-for-each-item-in-order)

Comment: Hello I am using woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item hook to add meta with key name as extra_charge , is it possible to show the key name as Extra Charge